# How to make function that split lazy list into two?

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

I need to make function that split lazy list. For example, [5;6;3;2;1] -> [5;3;1] and [6;2]. Here is syntax of regular lists, but it have to be lazy. Function split by index, odd to first list, even to second. I write function like this, but I don`t know how to add to lazy list new element:

```
let rec merge list = 
let rec mergeHelp list acc = function
    | LNil -> failwith "Empty list"
    | LCons(x, xf) ->
        if (acc mod 2 == 0)
        then LCons(x, function() -> mergeHelp (acc+1) (xf())), LCons(LNil, function() -> LNil)
        else LCons(LNil, function() -> LNil), LCons(x, function() -> mergeHelp (acc+1) (xf()))
in mergeHelp list 0
;;
```

Comment: Maybe start by thinking about the slightly simpler problem: how do you implement `List.filter` for lazy lists? I.e., write a function that takes a predicate (function returning bool) and a lazy list, and returns a new lazy list containing just the elements for which the predicate is true. The hint is that you don't need to add any elements to any lists to make this work. It's just a filtering operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know what your lazy list type is but I’m going to assume from your code it looks like:

```
type 'a t = LNil | LCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a t)
```

Note that this is different from a more typical lazy list where `(unit -> 'a t)` would be `'a t lazy`.

Chances are that the two lists won’t be consumed in the same way they are generated and we won’t want to scan through the input running all the functions once for the odds and again for the evens. So let’s write a function to pair up elements:

```
let rec pair = function 
  | LNil -> LNil
  | LCons (fst, rest) ->
    match rest () with
    | LNil -> LCons ((fst, None), const LNil)
    | LCons (snd, rest) ->
      let later_pairs = lazy (pair rest()) in
      LCons ((fst, Some snd), fun () -> Lazy.force later_pairs)
```

This function has type `'a t -> ('a * 'a option) t` and the key feature that once you have scanned it once, it is cheap to scan again as you do not recommits the elements of the output. The types are a little bit sad because really we are only allowed `None` for the second element in the last element of the result but let us live with that and carry on. First we need some trivial utilities:

```
let rec map f = function
  | LNil -> LNil
  | LCons (a, r) -> LCons (f a, fun () -> map f (r ()))

let rec filter_map f = function
  | LNil -> LNil
  | LCons (x, r) ->
    let r () = filter_map f (r ()) in
    match f x with
    | None -> r ()
    | Some a -> LCons (a, r)
```

These have types `('a -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b t` and `('a -> 'b option) -> 'a t -> 'b t` and do the least stupid thing one would guess from reading the type signature. We can now implement the function that does what you want:

```
let unmerge xs =
  let pairs = pair xs in
  (map (fun (a,_) -> a) pairs, filter_map (fun (_,b) -> b) pairs)
```

Comment: Sorry, that I don not give type of lazy list, it looks like: type 'a lazyList = LNil | LCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazyList);;
Can you explain me from where you take function filter_some and pair, because there no in standard library and I don not see the definition in your answer?

Comment: @Ilya sorry. Those were typos.

Comment: I make a little change in your code that hint to me terminal.
I tried function for: _________pair (LCons(2, function() -> LCons(3, function() -> LCons(4, function() -> LCons(6, function() -> LNil)))));;________ and get the result _________ - : (int * int option) lazyList = LCons ((2, Some 3), <fun>) _________ so isn`t it one lazy list with tuple elements, or this is just representation of two lazy lists?

Comment: Yes, that’s what pair does. It breaks up the list into pairs of elements. Then `unmerge` gives two lists.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks a lot for help)